# TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I got an error TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration.

```
data = libraries.pd.read_csv('a.csv',header=1, parse_dates=True)
datas = DataCleaning.DataCleaning(data)
datas.cleaning(media)

calDf = datas.getDatas()

array_x = libraries.np.int32(libraries.np.zeros(len(calDf)))
array_y = libraries.np.int32(libraries.np.zeros(len(calDf)))


if len(calDf) > 1:
    for num in range(len(calDf)):
        array_x[num] = calDf.iloc[num,0]
        array_y[num] = calDf.iloc[num,1]

    def nonlinear_fit(x,a,b):
        return  b * libraries.np.exp(x / (a+x))

    prameter_initial = libraries.np.array([0,0])

    try:
        param, cov = libraries.curve_fit(nonlinear_fit, array_x, array_y, maxfev=5000)

    except RuntimeError:
        print("Error - curve_fit failed")

li_result = []
li_result = zip(y, array_x, array_y)
```

I think the part of `zip(y, array_x, array_y)` is wrong because zip's arguments are not list type,so I wrote

```
for i in y:
 li_result = []
 li_result = zip(y, array_x[i], array_y[i])
```

but I got an error,

```
li_result = zip(y, array_x[i], array_y[i])
```

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

So, I cannot understand how to fix this.
What should I do?

Comment: Tell us the nature of `y`, `array_x` and `array_y`.  If arrays tell us the shape.  And what's the purpose of the `zip`?  Why is `li_result` assigned twice?

Comment: y is string type and it is item name. array_x is int type,it is price.  array_y is int type,it is stock count.I wanna make a list of these data,futhermore I make the list has all item data.So my ideal list has like [('itemA', 1000, 100), ('itemB', 2000, 2000), ('itemC', 300, 5000)].

Comment: I read zip function is only for series(like list). y, array_x and array_y are string&int,so is it wrong?

Comment: so `y` is a list of strings?

Comment: No.y is item name.y is in itemNameList like [itemA,itemB,itemC] 
y is these elements of list.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have three arrays `itemNameList`, `array_x`, and `array_y`

Assuming they are all the same shape, you can just do:

```
zipped = zip(itemNameList,array_x,array_y)
li_result = list(zipped)
```

**EDIT**

Your problem is that `array_x` and `array_y` are not actual `numpy.array` objects, but likely `numpy.int32` (or some other non-iterable) objects:

```
array_x = np.int32(np.zeros(None))
array_x.shape
# ()
array_x.__iter__
# AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute '__iter__'
```

Perhaps their initialization is not going as expected, or they are being changed from arrays somewhere in your code?

Comment: print `array_x.shape` and `array_y.shape` and reply with result

Comment: I wrote     print(array_x.shape)
    print(array_y.shape)    but ()()  are print out.

Comment: thx ur commetns.array_x and array_y's  initialization are not done,so is it wrong point?I thought array_x and array_y are variable so  their initialization are not needed.

Comment: are you sure that `array_x = libraries.np.int32(libraries.np.zeros(len(calDf)))` is working like you'd expect? Is `array_x` iterable directly following this line?

Comment: When I print out array_x,the result is like [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
So,I think the code is good....

Comment: how about `array_y`?

Comment: array_y is like[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
It is same

Comment: `array_y` and `array_x` look like this right before you attempt to `zip` them?

Comment: ur point is right!!before zip,print(array_x)&print(array_y) are printed out 0

Answer (score 0):

Here's how `zip` (or list(zip in py3), can turn several lists into a list of tuples:

```
In [76]: y = ['item1', 'item2','item3']  # list of strings
In [77]: xdata = [100,200,300]         # list of numbers
In [78]: ydata = np.array([1000,2000,3000])  # equivalent array of numbers
In [79]: list(zip(y,xdata,ydata))
Out[79]: [('item1', 100, 1000), ('item2', 200, 2000), ('item3', 300, 3000)]
```

Comment: thx ur comments.I cannot understand why is only this part of In [78]: ydata = np.array([1000,2000,3000])  used array function?I think  ydata is alrerady list type.

Comment: Just to show that an array can be zipped like a list